# How to implement an abstract class of generic type?

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance, tree

I'm woriking on a Java project regarding binary search trees. We were asked to implenet and AVL tree, but also advised to keep good abstraction in order to implement other types of trees (such as red-black tree). I decided to use an `abstract BsNode` class (Bs = binary search) and an `abstract BsTree` class, and implement them with `AvlTree` and `AvlNode` in the following way:

```java
public abstract class BsNode<T extends BsNode> {
    T parent
    T left
    T right
    ...
}

public abstract class BsTree<T extends BsNode> {
    T root
    ...
}

public class AvlNode extends BsNode<AvlNode> {
    int balance;
    ...
}

public class AvlTree<AvlNode> {
    private void rotate(int direction);
    ...
}
```

This causes two problems: First, it doesn't make sence to me that `BsNode` needs to receive it's inheritor type. Second, this opens the possibilty for such a thing to happen:

```java
public class RedBlackNode extends BsNode<AvlNode> {
    ...
}
```

or

```java
RedBlackNode myRoot = new RedBlackNode<AvlNode>();
```

and these should not be allowed. How can I enforce the usage of the inheriting class in `BsNode` (meaning to keep the `parent` and children pointers to the type that is implementing the class) instead of passing the `T` generic variable?

Comment: `BsNode<T extends BsNode<T>>`. Otherwise it's a raw type.

Comment: You can not forbid the misuse, only make it harder.

Comment: @AndyTurner but this still does not prevent the `public class RedBlackNode extends BsNode<AvlNode>` situation, and also requires `(T)` down-casting when reffering to `this`.

Comment: No, it does not require casting anything.

Comment: `BsNode` has a recursive `T containsNode(int searchVal)` method. assuming the value is found, I want to return `this` (as the node that contains the given value), but `this` reffers to a `BsNode<T>` and not just a `T`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments this is not possible to enforce at compilation time. There is a trick to force it to fail at run-time.

What you do is to request implementing classes to pass their own type-parameter class to the the abstract constructor with an argument typed with the type-parameter class.

The parent class constructor verifies that indeed this's class is the same class as the class that corresponds to the type-parameter's.

```
abstract class BsNode<T extends BsNode<T>> {

   protected BsNode(final Class<T> clazz) {
       if (!this.getClass().equals(clazz)) 
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid mixture of node types");
   } 
}

class AvlNode extends BsNode<AvlNode> {

   public AvlNode() {
        super(AvlNode.class); // works!!!
   }

}

class RBNode extends BsNode<AvlNode> {

   public RBNode() {
       // two possible super calls:
       super(AvlNode.class); // fails at run-time.
       // or
       super(RBNode.class); // fail at compilation-time.
   }
}
```

If you have a formal build process as part of your software that contains testing, it might make more sense to leave the constrain check out of the production code (saving the computation time) and instead make it part of your unit-tests.

Comment: as far as I noticed, I can't send `this` to `super(T)`, because before `super` is initialized `this` is not defined yet...

Comment: @A.Kali Thanks you are right! I fixed it by passing the presumed type-parameter class instead.

Comment: I didn't quite get, what does `T extends BsNode<T>` mean and how should I interpret it. It's a bit confusing to me. T is of type that is a child class of BsNode<T> or BsNode itself. Just `T extends BsNode` without the <T> at the end seems right. Could you explain what's happening there?